# How to find one vector of $w$ in the Euclidean inner product inside a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

if $\langle~~,~\rangle$ symbolizes the Euclidean inner product inside the vector space $\Bbb R^3$, find one vector of w for which

$\langle w,v_1 \rangle + \langle w,v_2 \rangle = 2 \langle w,v_3 \rangle$

where $v_1= [1,0,1], v_2 = [1,2,1], v_3 = [1,3,10]$

How can I solve this?

Comment: do you have a formula for $\langle x, y\rangle$?

Comment: This is easy, just take $w=0$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your posts and explain your attempts at solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want $w$ to be orthogonal to $v_1+v_2-2v_3$. Just take $w$ to be the cross product of this vector with any other not parallel to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let the unknown vector $w = [x, y, z]$ where $(x, y, z)$ are variables. Now, plug it into the given constraints:
\begin{align*}
&\langle w, v_1\rangle + \langle w, v2\rangle = 2 \langle w, v_3 \rangle \\
&\langle [x, y, z], [1, 0, 1]\rangle + \langle [x, y, z], [1, 2, 1]\rangle = 2 \langle [x, y, z], [1, 3, 10] \rangle \\
&(x +z) + (x + 2y + z)  = 2(x+3y+10z) \\
&2x + 2y+2z = 2x + 6y + 20z \\
&2y + 2z = 6y + 20z \\
&-4y = 18z \\
&y = \frac{-18z}{4} 
\end{align*}

So,we have no constraints on $x$, and we know that $y = \frac{-18z}{4}$. Therefore, 
$w = [x, -18z/4, z], \forall x, z \in \mathbb R$